# Необработанное исключение по адресу ... Переполнение стека

Tags: c++, рекурсия

После компиляции программы возникает следующая ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00212C39 в funccii.exe:
> 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (параметры: 0x00000001, 0x00052F6C).

Код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;
int cz;//Первый параметр в функции
int rt;//Второй параметр в функции

void PlusPlus(int ab, int  cd)
{
    if (ab < 10 || cd == 20)
    {
        cout << "That's ok" << endl;
        cout << "Your's numbers:" << ab << " and " << cd << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        PlusPlus(cz, rt);//Я уверен что ошибка в этой строчке кода
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    cout << "Введите первое число:";
    cin >> cz;
    cout << "Введите второе число:";
    cin >> rt;
    PlusPlus(cz, rt);
    cout << "Value of ou\t" << cz << endl;
    cout << "Value of mai\t" << rt << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Логика программы должна быть такой:

Пользователь вводит 2 числа(`cz` и `rt`), далее вызывается функция `PlusPlus()`.

Если первое число меньше `10`, а второе число равняется `20`, то всё хорошо и числа выводятся.

В противном случае я хотел чтобы был возврат в эту же функцию до тех пор пока пользователь не введет числа, которые подходили бы по условию.

Я знаю что это можно сделать с помощью цикла `while`, но у меня вопрос: Почему нельзя сделать возврат внутри els-а в эту же самую функцию?

Или если это возможно, то как это реализовать?

Comment: Вы пишите, что _Если первое число меньше 10, `А` второе число равняется 20_, то есть подразумеваются вот такая проверка `if(первое < 10 && второе == 20)`??. Мне просто для себя интересно узнать :)

Comment: Да,я перепутал || с && .Спасибо что заметили.Вообще сначала хотел сделать  как Вы написали : if(первое < 10 && второе == 20).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз уж вы предпочитаете глобальные переменные - то хотя бы так:

```
int cz, rt;

void PlusPlus()
{
    cout << "Введите первое число:" ;
    cin >> cz;
    cout << "Введите второе число:" ;
    cin >> rt;

    if (cz < 10 || rt == 20)
    {
        cout << "That's ok" << endl;
        cout<<"Your's numbers:" << cz << " and " << rt << endl;
        return;
    }
    PlusPlus();
}
int main()
{
    PlusPlus();
    cout << "Value of ou\t" << cz << endl;
    cout << "Value of mai\t" << rt << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Будет глупый вопрос,но в конструкции if/else зачем нужен return???Можете объяснить что он делает???

Comment: Просто не видел что кто-нибудь так делал...Даже не знал что так можно

Comment: Кстати,спасибо за ответ!!!

Comment: `return` всегда и везде выполняет выход их текущей функции.

Comment: Ну это понятно,спасибо конечно ,но разве при выходе из области видимости функция не завершается автоматически???Или я не прав???

Comment: Конечно. Можно и так, как у вас - `if () Х ...} else { PlusPlus(); }` - это то же самое. Просто мне захотелось переписать вот так, явно выделив условие выхода.

Comment: Понял,выход из самой функции а не из области видимости цикла if/else.Реально не знал что так работает return.Спасибо за уделенное время,жалко нельзя поставить 2 ответа как лучшие...

Answer (score 2):

Ну если параметры никогда не меняются, то и рекурсия никогда не закончится. А вот стек закончится - от ты и получаешь переполнение стека.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключается в том, что если пользователь ввел не подходящие числа, то вы не просите его ввести новые, а проверяете на тех же. При этом каждый вызов функции `PlusPlus` добавляется в стек, но ни один из вызовов не завершается. По этому у вас переполняется стек и выдает ошибку.

Вот пример кода через ссылки, без глобальных перемен:

```
void PlusPlus(int& ab, int& cd) {
    //Просим пользователя ввести числа
    cout << "Введите первое число:";
    cin >> ab;
    cout << "Введите второе число:";
    cin >> cd;
    
    //Если числа подходят, то выводим их.
    if (ab < 10 || cd == 20) {
        cout << "That's ok" << endl;
        cout << "Your's numbers:" << ab << " and " << cd << endl;
    }
    //Иначе вызываем опять эту функцию, в начале которой
    //мы опять попросим пользователя ввести числа
    else PlusPlus(ab, cd);
}

int main()
{
    int cz, rt;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    PlusPlus(cz, rt);
    cout << "Value of ou\t" << cz << endl;
    cout << "Value of mai\t" << rt << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот сколько я сижу на сайте, но никогда не пойму, за что голосуют против ответа, когда он отвечает на поставленный вопрос, объясняя проблему и есть код с комментариями, а не просто код без слов. Наверно потому, что у меня не 159к репутации :(

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ,и за объяснение.После компиляции,понял в чем ошибка была.Поставлю Ваш ответ как лучший,а то несправедливо получается)))

Comment: Гм, если ваши 159k намек, что вас минусовал я - увы, это не так :) А вообще, я сейчас посмотрел - мне за все время влепили 317 минусов, так что вы не одиноки :) Вам - только 9. Так что наши "удельные минусации" :) не так чтоб на порядки отличались...

Comment: @Harry нет я не намекал на вас, я намекал на то, что чем больше у тебя репутации тем больше за твой ответ будут голосовать, и есть такие кто голосуют против если у человека мало репутации, и даже если ответ хороший.